# Comparing JDBCTemplate and Hibernate for data access using spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I have used both jdbcTemplate and Hibernate, but I am having a hard time comparing jdbcTemplate and hibernate in the context of performance, query execution time and batch updates.

**My View and research did so far.**

1. As hibernate uses HQL then its query is first translated into native language query and after that query is executed. So query execution time is high in case of hibernate(that's a different case as hibernate also support native query).
2. As Hibernate is ORM tool so we don't have to create the DataBase schema.
3. The batch insert of records is not piece of cake in hibernate as if the generation type of PK is Identity then batch insert won't be performed.

Is there are any other point when comparing JDBCTemplate and hibernate and when to use what?